# Gitea 1.19.3, Enable Status Check option greyed out, how to enable?

Tags: gitea

I am an administrator of a  Gitea 1.19.3 server and I would like to enable merge checks on PR's before I can merge my code. I figured to go into the Branch Protection settings but I have that the option I think I want to enable is greyed out.

First of all, is this the option I want?
And second, how do I enable it if it is what I want?

[image: The greyed out option]